# Comentar linea en Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

¿Cómo puedo comentar una línea en un template de `Laravel` que contiene `@include`, `@section`, `@endsection` e incluso `img src"{{ asset('libs/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.js') }}"`

He intentado con

- `<!-- -->`
- `//`
- `/*`

pero aun no trato de convencerme de que esté bien hecho.

Comment: Bueno ya te respondieron, pero agrego que cuando comentas como usualmente se hace en html '<!-- -->', blade (motor de plantilla) de laravel no lo renderiza como un comentario, tienes que a fuerzas usar la sintaxis de blade '{{-- --}}'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
{{-- Esto es un comentario --}}
```

Comment: me puedes explicar que hace este tipo de comentar una linea? comenta toda la linea sin importar la sintaxis? Sin importar si es html,css, o javascript... Explícame mejor tu respuesta gracias.

Comment: siempre que estes usando helpers de blade como el  {{ asset('libs/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.js') }} el comentado se debe hacer asi

Comment: Pero entonces también comenta código como @section @endsection?

Comment: ¿Sabéis por qué no funciona este tipo de comentar línea en Windows?
Pensaba que era por una versión antigua de windows, pero ni me funcionaba ni en la 7 ni en la 10...se me queda el wamp pillado y no carga la página cómo tenga algún comentario con la forma {{-- --}}

Answer (score 2):

El comentario para las plantillas blade de laravel es:

```
{{-- bla bla bla --}}
```

Estas llaves comentan no sólo los elementos html de tu plantilla sino también estructuras como:

```
@section
@yield
@if()....@endif
...
```

Mientras que el comentario de html  sólo comentará las etiquetas html que haya dentro de ellas (pero no el código php), las etiquetas de blade {{-- --}} comentarán ambos.

Es decir:

En ambos casos, el contenido PHP se procesará:

```
<!-- <span><?php echo $saludo ?></span> --> 
<!-- <span>@content('bloque')</span> -->
```

En cambio, en estos casos no:

```
{{-- <span><?php echo $saludo ?></span> --}} 
{{-- <span>@content('bloque')</span> --}}
```